# go runでコンパイルされるバイナリはどこかに保存される？

Tags: go

go言語で以下のようにコマンドを実行すると"compile and run Go program"するとUsageに書かれているが、compileされたバイナリはどこかに保存されますか？

```
$ go run hello.go
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[go コマンドのドキュメント](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)によると、-work オプションをつけると go run でコンパイルされたバイナリが格納されているテンポラリディレクトリを削除せずに残しておいてくれて、そのディレクトリ名が表示されるそうです。

```
$ go run -work hello.go
WORK=/tmp/go-build943288373
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。-workオプションなんてのがあるんですね。

Answer (score 1):

コンパイルして実行ファイルを作成する場合、"go build"コマンドが使えます

```
go build hello.go
```